# ReactJS tutorial. Why an input value needs to be set from this.state if it is not used anywhere else?

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty new to JS and React, so it's for sure my misunderstanding, but can anyone tell me what for the input here needs to be assigned with this.state?
It's an example from React tutorial, chapter 10.Lifting State Up.
It works without that line...Thank you!!

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: ''};
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in Celsius:</legend>
        <input
          value={temperature}                                  //here it is
          onChange={this.handleChange} />

        <BoilingVerdict
          celsius={parseFloat(temperature)} />

      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is used in input element. You need to set into a state variable what you type in the input field and assign that state variable to input value prop so that whatever you type will be appeared in the input text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that the input "needs" to be assigned to a value from `this.state`, but it sort of makes the most sense to do it that way with rendering frameworks like React.

The reason the example works without the line is because the input essentially has it's own internal value, which when modified is communicated to your component with the `handleChange` callback. There's nothing keeping that internal value in sync with your state, so if for some reason the input were reconstructed or something, that correspondence would be lost (your component's state would not reflect what's in the input). Additionally, if you wanted to set a starting value for your state and the input (other than an empty input), by tethering the value of the input to your state, you can just set the default value in `this.state`.

Think about it like this: giving the input a value from `this.state` as in the example (along with an update callback) binds it directly to your state whereby your code controls how and when it changes. There's no way for them to get out of sync this way, one of great features these rendering frameworks provide.

Comment: ok, that makes sense to me. But I can't imagine how the input could be reconstructed.

Comment: I can't exactly formulate a circumstance where this would happen either off the top of my head, but the thing that makes me feel uneasy is the fact that they aren't tethered. By binding the value of the input, there's simply no way they can get out of sync -- which is a great guarantee to have. Without doing so, something could cause them to get out of sync and create a pretty nightmarish bug.